# Cannot execute *quick sort* script in matlab (from Engineering Computation with matlab book - Smith)

Tags: matlab, quicksort

The script lies on page 438 of the book, 2nd edition. Here it is:

```
function a = quicksort(a, from, to)
clear, clc, close all

if (from < to)
[a p] = partition(a, from, to);
a = quicksort(a, from, p);
a = quicksort(a, p+1, to);
end

function [a lower] = partition(from,to)

pivot = a(from); i = from - 1; j = to + 1;
while (i<j)
i = i + 1;
while lt(a(i),pivot)
    i = i + 1;
end
j = j - 1;
while gt(a(j), pivot)
    j = j - 1;
end
if (i<j)
    temp = a(i);
    a(i) = a(j);
    a(j) = temp;
end
end
lower = j;
a
```

I fail to execute the script to see the result and I keep receiving the following error (even if I modify the inputs):

```
??? Error using ==> quicksort>partition
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> quicksort at 9
[a p] = partition(a, from, to);
```

Can someone please help me? I'm very interested in these Matlab sorting techniques. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* call `clear all, clc, close all` inside a function. You shouldn't even call it from inside a script, in my opinion.

Also, the call to `partition` has too many input arguments, as the error says. In fact, the function `partition` should be defined as `partition(a, from, to)`, instead of `partition(from,to)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I'm very confident at using functions atm.

Comment: @Pegasus99: Glad to hear! As for myself, I still keep learning new things after all these years.